# Where to open and close the NHibernate ISession in a web app (specifically MVC)?

Tags: nhibernate, session, orm

This is a pretty fundamental question when using NHibernate in a web application, but I don't see any agreed best practice when searching the web.  I've seen it done in lots of different places:

**Created and disposed in the Repository method** - This just seems silly to me, since when you get the object it's already detached.

**At the beginning and end of the Controller Action** - This seems better, but annoying to have to do it for each action.

**At the Application level, in global.asax beginrequest and endrequest** -  This seems the best idea, but again, I've seen some examples creating in Init instead of beginrequest (sharp architecture for instance) - although I am not sure why.

Maybe there are other approaches?
Can IoC containers help in some way here?
Maybe you know of a good resource on the web regarding this?
And - what method do you use?

Thanks

Comment: Sharp Architecture explains why - it's something with IIS7 as far as I remember.

Comment: Well in the code comments it says: "Due to issues on IIS7, the NHibernate initialization must occur in Init().", but I don't know what the issues are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Session per Request](http://www.ryanlanciaux.com/2008/05/11/nhibernate-session-per-request/) is probably the most used approach.

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen some examples creating in Init instead of beginrequest (sharp architecture for instance) - although I am not sure why.

In IIS 7 You can have access to the Session state in the Init event of Global.asax. That's why  sharp arch uses beginrequest.

As for session management I agree with you - Global.asax is the best place for it. Event if you want to have a clean separation between layers and remove DAL settings from UI you can use  [HttpModule](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/06/12/146356.aspx) for it.

Also you can have a look at [ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/05/do-you-need-a-framework.aspx). It explains his way of session management

Comment: Hi Sly, but why do you need to use the ASP.NET session state?  And why not just put it in Application_Start?

Comment: You need session state to store ISession of the NHibernate.
You cant do it in Application_Start because you cant have access to the ApplicationState- and you need it to put SessionFactory in it

Comment: Most of the solutions I have been looking at do not use session state, rather HttpContext.Items or a static member.